# Django Form Field Not Setting Value After Submitting

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I'm trying to post data from a form that contains incomplete data (I set the missing data in the `View` class before saving) for the following model. But the form does not get submitted as it is invalid (it's missing the `harvest_amount`, but I set the value on the webpage before submitting.

```
class Harvest(models.Model):
    harvest_amount = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(limit_value=0)])
    harvest_date = models.DateField()
    harvest_for_plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and my form

```
class HarvestCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
            model = Harvest
             fields = [
                'harvest_amount'
             ]

       def is_valid(self):
           //check if Id in the url contains a valid id for a plant
           return True
```

Comment: in modelform the validation method is called clean or if you want to validate harvest_amount you can call clean_harvest_amount ,  is valid method exists in createview, update view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I forgot to migrate my changes to the model (where a field was deleted). When the form posted the data it would always hit the not null constraint since the deleted field was not being set.